# Reactjs mounting state before initial render or keep as is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

State on the initial render here is the initial state.  Am using componentWillMount() however it won't work without first checking whether the component is mounted.  The result when using rawMarkup() is an empty initial state object.  Everything functions properly on the re-render but wondering why the post object within state is still empty on the initial render.  Is there a better way of accomplishing this?  Thank you.

```
var Post = React.createClass({
propTypes: {
    source: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
},

getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        post: {}
    };
},

getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
        source: 'http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + postSlug
    };
},

componentWillMount: function() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
        if (this.isMounted()) {
            this.setState({post: result});
        }
    }.bind(this));
},

rawMarkup: function() {
    console.log(this.state.post);
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.state.post.body || '', {sanitize: true});
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
 },

render: function() {
    var post = this.state.post;
    var date = moment(post.date).format('MM[/]DD[/]YYYY');
    return (
        React.createElement('div', {style: {marginLeft: '115px'}},
            React.createElement('h1', {style: {marginTop: '50px'}}, post.title),
            React.createElement('h5', {style: {marginBottom: '25px'}}, date),
            React.createElement('span', {dangerouslySetInnerHTML: this.rawMarkup()})
        )
    );
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the jQuery get request is asynchronous, so the initial render happens before the request completes and `this.setState({post: result})` is called.  You could make the get request synchronous ([How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)), or figure out a way to gracefully deal with no data on the initial render (recommended).

Comment: Yes this makes sense thank you.  Received further helpful input through another medium and set the initial post state to null with an if() statement in the render to check for state's preparedness.